# Averaging a number of files from a folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that pulls from a folder path, reads the files (each is a 2 by inf array) in sets of n, averages the second row of each file by column and writes those results out to an excel file. I expect this to loop until I have reached the end of the files in the folder.
For example the function is given a file path and an n value. ie.(path,2) each of the following arrays would be a different file in the path to the folder. The code would average the second row of each array and output the average row-by-row.

Example:

```
[1,2;3,4] [1,2;5,6]
[1,2;7,8] [1,2;9,10]
[1,2;3,4] [1,2;9,10]
```

would output in an excel file:

```
4 5
8 9
6 7
```

This is my current code:

```
def fileavg(path,n):
    import numpy as np
    import xlsxwriter
    from glob import glob

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    row=0
    
    glob.iglob(path) #when inputting path name begin with r' and end with a '
    for i in range(0,len(1),n):
        f=yield 1[i:i +n]
        A=np.mean(f(1),axis=1)
        for col, data in enumerate(A):
            worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
        row +=1
```

I receive a generator object error when I attempt to run the function. Please let me know what this means and where any mistakes might be as I'm quite new to python.

Comment: What is `range(0,len(1),n)` supposed to mean? The argument to `len()` can't be a number.

Comment: `yield 1[i:i +n]` also doesn't make sense, you can't slice a number.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, but my advise would be to use high level libraries. Use `pathlib` and its `glob` method to first get a list of files you want to read. Then iterate over that list, load every file with `pandas.read_csv`, concatenate that all into a single dataframe every `n` batches, do the averaging you want to do and write that out with the `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` method.